# How to Resolve Empty Relationships in jsonapi Format with a Custom Normalizer in API Platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, jsonapi-resources

I'm using `API Platform` with `jsonapi` format and a custom normalizer to resolve entities and their relationships. In my custom item normalizer, I'm using the `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface` class. However, I'm having trouble resolving empty relationships with the `jsonapi` format normalizer after normalizing the entity. I've tried passing `skip_null_values` as false but it didn't work.

Here's my custom normalizer class:

```
class ApiItemNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface, SerializerAwareInterface
{
    public function __construct(private readonly NormalizerInterface $decorated, ...) { ... }

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $responseObject = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);
        ...
     }
}
```

I would like to resolve the entity relationship whether it is empty or not. However, the jsonapi format normalizer ignores the empty relationship:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "does not have any relation",
        "created_at": "2023-04-24T11:46:16+02:00",
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "have two relations",
        "created_at": "2023-04-13T11:37:53+02:00",
        "category": [
            {
               "name": "cat 1",
                "updated_by": null,
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "cat 2",
                "updated_by": null,
                "id": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I resolve the category attribute in the first item with an empty array as a value?